# R: If Statement - Only print once even though if statement is met several times

Tags: r, break

I constructed a reproducible code below. I want to only print out ONCE even though the condition is met several times. For example, in below code, when `i > 6`, that is `i=7,8,9,10`, print out YES. But I only want to print out YES one time, which is the first time the condition is met. Then exit this `for` loop.

The reason I'm doing this is because I have extremely large database, and once condition is met, I print out "YES". I don't want to print out several "YES", because it's not what I want, and it will increase the execution time.

```
x <- 1:10
for (i in 1:10){
if (i > 6){
print("YES")
}
}
```

Comment: What is `x` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. Insert a `break` statement to stop the loop after it prints "YES" when `x > 7`:

```r
x <- 1:10
for (i in 1:10){
  if (i > 6){
    print("YES")
    break
  }
}
```